# Padding element with position: relative

Tags: html

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: crimson;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>We're studying second line padding</span>
</p>
```

Why does the second line padding flow over the first line, both are the same span element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, `<span>` is an inline element and it doesn't mind the padding in the top and bottom. Inline elements tend to flow with the content and also do not respect the box model of the top and bottom. So make the `<span>` element as `inline-block`:

```css
span {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: crimson;
  padding: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: crimson;
  padding: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p><span> We're studying second line padding</span></p>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]